# Using du to look for file types in a directory tree?

Tags: shell, du

I know that `du *.txt` for example gives me all the .txt files in the current directory, but can I somehow modify the command to look through not just the root directory but all the other directories within to find all the .txt files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this:

`find . -name "*.txt" -exec du -skh {} \;` ?

Comment: For the "*.txt" part, it says no such file or directory.

Comment: That's strange. For me: `find . -name "*.ffsf" -exec du -skh {} \;` returns nothing as the list is empty (trying a non-existent extension).

Comment: @Daeto - that's strange. What OS are you running?

Comment: Oh I think it just started working! Thanks a lot Kedar!

Answer (score 0):

You may combine the find command with the du command to get the result:

```
find . -name \*.txt | du
```

Comment: @Daeto sorry, it's simply du

Comment: No thats not working, it lists everything, not just the files with the given extension.

Comment: @Daeto - are you sure you are using the standard `find` command that was provided by `findutils` package?

Comment: @Daeto Sorry again, i forgot the dot.